# AJAX login form

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am using spring login form right now. 
Which is similar to the example code which is in the link below.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Now I want to implement ajax login form with spring 
Please suggest how I can do it

```
<%
    String res = (String)request.getParameter("login_error");
    if(res!=null)
    {%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //alert("Invalid email address or password. Please try again.");
    $("#status p").html("Invalid email address or password. Please try   again.");
    document.getElementById('errormsg').style.display="block";
</script>
<%}

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a way to post your page/form in a particular manner to the server. Also it's a completely client side component which is implemented through JavaScript or JavaScript based libraries like jquery.

So keeping in mind; will suggest you to read about Ajax and then you can integrate with your application. You can start from here http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials/

Comment: Thank for the info. I know jquery a little bit. But not getting how to integrate it with my code.

Comment: I have added the code where if login fails I am showing an alert right. I dont want to reload whole page if ligin fails I just want reload the login form with an error message below the form

Comment: Yeah; through Ajax you don't need to load whole page. I will suggest; you try first jquery and ajax and then try to integrate with your existing code...